# Functional of length of curve is not continuous with respect to the norm as follows.

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $J[y] = \int_a^b \sqrt{1+y'^2}$ be the functional of length of curve.
Let $C([a,b])$ be a function space consisting of all continuous function $y(x)$ defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$.

Define a norm, $||y||$, by
$||y|| = \max_{a\le x \le b} |y(x)|$.

Show that this functional, $J[y]$, is indeed not continuous with respect to this norm.

What I knows:
We firstly fixed a curve, say $\hat{y}$.
Then, we must find a function $y$ such that $y \to \hat{y}$, but $J[y] - J[\hat{y}]$ is sufficiently large. But, I didn't know yet how to pick a such function and apply the epsilon-delta definition of discontinuous function. How to show it? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: First think intuitively: the norm $\|\cdot\|$ you've defined only controls the values of the function. It says nothing about the derivative. On the other hand, in the definition of $J(y)$, the derivative $y'$ appears. So, can you start by thinking of a sequence of functions $y_n$, such that $y_n$'s are "uniformly close" together, but such that their derivatives are not (again, remember the derivatives can exhibit some crazy behavior). Also, you should mention that $J$ is only defined on a subspace say $C^1([a,b])$ of $C([a,b])$.

Comment: It is possible for two continuous functions to be *close* in the max-norm, but for their derivatives to be far apart (or not to exist at all).  So the way the functional $J$ depends on the derivative $y'$ rather than just on $y$ itself should suggest an family  of examples.

Comment: @peek-a-boo What is uniformly close? I still confuse

Comment: Asking whether $J$ is continuous on $C[a,b]$ doesn't make much sense, since $J$ is not even _defined_ on $C[a,b]$.

Comment: Can you explain me about this statement please? "For every curve, we can find another curve arbitrarily close the first in the sense of the norm of the space $C([a,b])$, whose length differs from that of the first curve by a factor of 10, say." This is a hint of what I asked above, but I didn't get it yet.